# Changing data of a new element in array changes every element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with angular and i want to add new elements in an array.
The array is displayed on GUI after you click a button.

My current array looks like this:

```
[ {name: 'user1', percentage: '1'} ]
```

After you click the button the array must be:

```
[ 
   {name: 'user1', percentage: '1'}, 
   {name: 'user1', percentage: '0'} 
]
```

My problem is adding another element changes every percentage to 0 like this:

```
[ 
   {name: 'user1', percentage: '0'},
   {name: 'user1', percentage: '0'} 
]
```

My code for the array and add new element function:

```
accData:any = [];

new(){
    
    this.accData.push(this.accData[this.accData.length - 1]);
    this.accData[this.accData.length - 1].percentage = '0';

    console.log(this.accData)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS has reference semantics.

The elements in your array are references to objects located on a heap.
You need to create a new object and add it to the array, not copy an existing reference.

Object spread syntax is an elegant way to copy existing object, and allows to change some props.

```ts
const accData = [ {name: 'user1', percentage: '1'} ];
const newElem = {...accData[accData.length - 1], percentage: '0'};
accData.push(newElem); // newElem can be inlined for brevity
```

Note that Object spread syntax makes a shallow copy - this is enough for your objects, but you may need a deep copy if you have nested properties.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
let accData = [ {name: 'user1', percentage: '1'} ];
accData.push({name: accData[0].name, percentage: (Number(accData[0].percentage) -1).toString()});

console.log(accData);
```